# Where do I put my 3rd party javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Edited:

I am building an app on platforms like shopify.com.  The platform will serve the 3rd party javascript (1st party - brower, 2nd party - shopify.com).  The rails app I am building is the backend.  It will not serve this javascript so it does not make sense to place it under assets pipeline. Conceptually, the 3rd party javascript is part of the app.

My question is how I should organize it so that it would clear to subsequent maintainers.

=====================

Original:

I am build a 3rd party javascript that is placed with a platform.  I am not serving this script directly.  Question is where do I put in within rails?  I thinking of creating a folder under app to do it.

Comment: Most of your question is very difficult to understand. What do you mean, "placed with a platform"? What do you mean "I am not serving this script directly"?  What do you mean by "I am build a 3rd party javascript"? Most of these statements aren't grammatically correct and are difficult to interpret.

Comment: I hear you.  I have fixed it in the edited question.  Platforms are shopify.com, tictail.com etc.  I am new and I thank you for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

`vendor/assets/javascripts` is specifically meant to house your 3rd party JS libraries.

Comment: Although the fact that you said you built it could also mean it could sit in the normal javascripts folder.  I normally keep the vendor reserved for things I download.

Comment: @JasonBrodie Honestly I'm really not sure what is going on here. He also said "placed with a platform" and " I am not serving this script directly". It's pretty unclear what is being asked here.

Comment: Sorry, I have not been clear.  Platforms are shopify.com, tictail.com etc.  They will insert my javascript when they render storefront.  Thus, I am not serving javascript directly